# Find all the countries I can visit by just crossing direct borders

Tags: sql, recursion, graph, postgresql

I was helping on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232275/recursion-in-postgresql/35234200#35234200). There you have a table border to indicate `countryA` and `countryB` have a common border. And want to know what country you can reach starting from country `S` Sweden.

I did my recursion and works ok. But I feel I cheat a little bit. Taking advantage the number of countries are limited put a break on 300. But in a different problem where I don't know the upper limit won't be able to do the same.

How I optimize my query so recursion doesn't travel the same path again?

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c4d9/7)**

```
WITH RECURSIVE travel(r_level, country) AS (
    select distinct 1 as r_level,
                    CASE WHEN country1 = 'S' THEN country2
                         ELSE country1          
                    END as country
    from borders 
    where country1 = 'S' 
       or country2 = 'S'    
    UNION 
    select distinct t.r_level + 1 as r_level,
                    CASE WHEN b.country1 = t.country THEN b.country2
                         ELSE b.country1
                    END as country           
    from borders b
    join travel  t
      ON (b.country1 = t.country OR b.country2 = t.country)
     AND (b.country1 <> 'S' AND b.country2 <> 'S')
    WHERE t.r_level < 300
)
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM travel
```

I can't use subquery based on the same recursive table:

```
AND (    b.country1 NOT IN (SELECT country FROM Travel)
     AND b.country2 NOT IN (SELECT country FROM Travel)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to artificially limit number of iterations, according to [PG manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) using `UNION` without `ALL` is enough:

> Recursive Query Evaluation
>
> 1. Evaluate the non-recursive term. For UNION (but not UNION ALL), **discard duplicate rows**. Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary working table.
> 2. So long as the working table is not empty, repeat these steps:
>
>    a) Evaluate the recursive term, substituting the current contents of the working table for the recursive self-reference. For UNION (but not UNION ALL), **discard duplicate rows and rows that duplicate any previous result row**. Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary intermediate table.
>
>    b) Replace the contents of the working table with the contents of the intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table.

```
with recursive travel(country) as (
  select 'S'
  union
  select unnest(array[country1, country2]::text[])
    from travel
      join borders on (country = any(array[country1, country2]))
)
select country from travel where country <> 'S';
```

Btw, the problem is related to calculating [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory) on a graph.